# No sound from speakers windows 11

Tags: drivers, windows-11, realtek-hd-audio

I have a computer with biostar ta970 ver 5.3 mb, amd phenom II x6 1090T, 64G RAM, windows 11.
The computer does not play sound. Sound property shows green when testing sound, but there is no sound. I tried many things.

**What I have done.**

- Installed Realtek HD Audio codec R2.82
- Installed All software and drivers from [Biostar website](https://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/eol/introduction.php?S_ID=748) for the mb. I don't know if there are other drivers.
- Checked the speaker is working with other music player. The speaker works with other music player.
- Checked rear/ front audio output with an earpohone. Not working.
- Ran Audio Trouble shoot from settings menu.
- Updated all sound drivers.
- Uninstalled and reinstalled sound drivers, realtek and other.
- Installed Realtek UAD driver ver 6.0.9282.1. Universal Driver.
- Asked microsoft technical support for windows 11 compatibility. Maybe sound driver, chipset drivers, or hardware issues.
- Asked Biostar mb e-support. Not responded yet.

Please tell me how to fix the problem.

Here is the computer details.

**My computer details**

- Processor AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1090T Processor 3.20 GHz
- RAM 64.0 GB
- System 64 bit os、x64 base processor
- Edition Windows 11 Pro
- Version 21H2
- Installed ‎2022/‎01/‎17
- OS Build 22000.556
- Experience WindowsExperience Pack 1000.22000.556.0
- MB Biostar TA970 ver 5.3 Realtek ALC892 codec

I have tried with my old Biostar mb A880+ with same CPU, 8GB RAM, and 2TB hd and it worked with all features icluding sounds and videos. It is just this mb not working with windows 11. The sound is the only problem and it is just driver(s) or minor problem(s) from the sound hardware.

Comment: Did sound work from the motherboard before installing Windows 11? If not, have you tried unplugging the front panel audio connector from the motherboard?

Comment: Your hardware isn't Windows 11 compatible so that's what Biostar will say, when and if they reply. Keep in mind that by overriding the compatibility check you opened yourself to all sorts of problems including the one you're reporting here.

Comment: @Andrew Morton As I added on the text, it worked with all features on my other mb. I checked the front jacks and all hardwares.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Microsoft states that because there are many users not meet the TPM2.0 and other requirements. It can be installed without comaptibility requirements. About 2/3 of the users are not compatible with the requirements without TPM2.0 and others which are not necessary and have no good security.  - TPM 2.0 only features not strong encryption standards and some AES256 and not strong encryptions. Maybe only effective on offline environments with hazards.

Comment: @ChanganAuto By ignoring the secuirty and other security concerns, the technological progresses make the hardwares, infrastructures, users to face with hazards and technological run-away. It has been the situations before, just as CPU clock speed problems. They can not pass electric current on CPU circuits with too much densed transistors with 4-2 nano technology. There is a limit on the electric circuits width which electic current to pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought a PCI card and works now. It was hardware.